# Can the launch of Falcon Heavy be seen well from the Rocket Garden?

Tags: launch, falcon-heavy, kennedy-space-center

Is any viewing of the falcon heavy launch visible from the $75 rocket garden ticket? Just trying to decide if it would be worth the money.

Comment: The Visitor Center is about as close as you can get to the *launch* of the Falcon Heavy. But the *landing* of the boosters (um, if they make it...) is best viewed from Jetty Park and Pier, 400 Jetty Park Rd, Port Canaveral, FL 32920. https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1GDVHkW9T1-8HhNN5BdMnxUvCGpU&hl=en_US&ll=28.513737034188267%2C-80.57224371412048&z=12

Answer (score 6):

From the [KSC Rocket Garden](https://www.kennedyspacecenter.com/info/tickets#) website, a $75 ticket gets you access to the KSC Visitor Complex. More expensive tickets get you closer (down to about 4 km).

> Where:
>
> Kennedy Space Center Visitor Complex, approximately 7.5 miles/ 12 kilometers with rocket visible shortly after lift off

12 km is very far away, the rocket will be a speck on the horizon, comparable with an airliner flying over at cruising altitude.